# The Development Server Returned Error Code:500 React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Hello every one I am pretty new to react native i am facing this error [image]
This is a SignIN/Sign up page for the project i am currently working on.I am running this on a physical device Samsung S7 edge running 8.0 Oreo

```html
**App.js***
import React from 'react'
import{StyleSheet,Text,View}from 'react-native'
import RegForm from '.app/Components/RegForm'
export default class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={Styles.Container}>
        <RegForm />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
const styles=StyleSheet.Create({
  container:{
    flex:1 ,
    justifyContent:'center',
    backgroundColor:'#36485f' ,
    paddingLeft:60 ,
    paddingRight:60 ,
  },
})
```

```html
***RegForm***
import React from 'react'
import{StyleSheet,Text,View,TextInput,TouchableOpacity}from 'react-native'

export default class RegForm extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={Styles.RegForm}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>Registration</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.TextInput} placeholder="Please Enter your Name" />
        <TextInput style={styles.TextInput} placeholder="Please Enter your Email" />
        <TextInput style={styles.TextInput} placeholder="Please Enter your Password"
        secureTextEntry={true} />
        <TextInput style={styles.TextInput} placeholder="Please Enter your Mobile No" />
        <TextInput style={styles.TextInput} placeholder="Please Enter your CNIC" />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.btntext}>Sign Up</Text>
        
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
const styles=StyleSheet.Create({
  RegForm:{
    alignSelf:'strech' ,
  },
  header:{
fontSize:24 ,
color:'#fff',
paddingBottom:10 ,
marginBottom:40 ,
borderBottomColor:'#199187',
borderBottomWidth:'1',
  },
  TextInput:{
      alignSelf:'strech',
      height:40 ,
      marginBottom:30 ,
      color:'#fff' ,
      borderBottomColor:'#f8f8f8',
      borderBottomWidth:1 ,
  },
  button:{
      alignSelf:'strech',
      alignItem:'center',
      padding:20 ,
      backgroundColor:'#59cbbd',
      marginTop:30 ,
  },
  btntext:{
      color:'#fff',
      fontWeight:'bold',

  }
})
```

Comment: where is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import RegForm from './app/Components/RegForm'
```

rather than

```
import RegForm from '.app/Components/RegForm'
```

Hope it helps. do revert in case of any concerns.

Comment: Any one please help this is very important to me